# Subsetting vectors with extract

Tags: r, magrittr

Imagine I have vector, and I want to remove a specific element. I could do the following

```
library(magrittr)

foo <- LETTERS[1:10]

foo %>% 
{
   bar <- .

   bar %>% 
     extract(bar %>% 
              equals("A") %>% 
              not)
}


[1] "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H" "I" "J"
```

But if I'd like to be more succinct, this:

```
foo %>% 
  extract(. %>% 
            equals("A") %>% 
            not)
```

doesn't work:

```
Error in extract(., . %>% equals("A") %>% not) : 
  invalid subscript type 'closure'
```

Isn't there are more idiomatically `magrittr`'y way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to pipe `foo` into the subsetting function `[`, limiting to elements that do not equal A using `!=`:

```
foo %>% "["(. != "A")
# [1] "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H" "I" "J"
```

The `magrittr` package has aliased `[` as `extract`, so this is equivalent to:

```
foo %>% extract(. != "A")
# [1] "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H" "I" "J"
```