# Subsetting a vector using pipe %>%

Tags: vector, pipe, subset

If I had a vector, how to subset this vector according to its value, but using pipe operator?
like x <- c(1:10), I want it returned 1:5 with %>% operation.

This bothers me because often after a few %>% , it returns a vector, and I want one step more from it.

```
x <- c(1:10)
x %>% is_less_than(5) # this returns T/F with length 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found answers from 
[Subsetting vectors with extract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35229178/subsetting-vectors-with-extract)

```r
x %>% extract(. <= 5)
```